# An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to <My wcf service deployed at IIS>

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

When I try to invoke my web service which is on a different server(Production) from asp.net server side web page, it gets executed without any exception sometimes and sometimes I get this exception mentioned in title. I have used wshttpbinding. I am also posting the complete stack trace. But the last inner exception says :

> Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: An existing connection was
>   forcibly closed by the remote host.

Based on my search,  somewhere it says its due to wrong binding , somewhere its written IIS permissions are blocking , and also small time out limits. I have increased the time out but have not altered bindings and IIS account because I believe had that been the problem it would not have executed successfully even once. The behavior is highly sporadic with 50% success rate. And also some users have reported this issue with normal asp.net calls also where no wcf is involved.

This webservice call does not takes any parameters and does not return any data either. (FireAndForget kind of scenerio).

Exception Message:

> An error occurred while receiving the
>   HTTP response to
>   https://json.clickable.com/BMS/NetSuiteCommunicationService.svc.
>   This could be due to the service
>   endpoint binding not using the HTTP
>   protocol. This could also be due to an
>   HTTP request context being aborted by
>   the server (possibly due to the
>   service shutting down). See server
>   logs for more details.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> Server stack trace:   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request,
>   HttpAbortReason abortReason)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.RequestClientReliableChannelBinder`1.OnRequest(TRequestChannel
>   channel, Message message, TimeSpan
>   timeout, MaskingMode maskingMode)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout, MaskingMode
>   maskingMode)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientReliableChannelBinder`1.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings`1.SecurityRequestSessionChannel.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String
>   action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)   at
>   Clickable.Scheduler.BLL.NetsuiteService.INetSuiteCommunicationService.ExecuteAddAdNetworkToCustomerTask()
>   at
>   Clickable.Scheduler.BLL.Configuration.Tasks.AdNetworkToCustomerTask.Run()
>   at
>   Clickable.Scheduler.BLL.Configuration.Tasks.Task.Excecute()
>
> Exception Message: The underlying
>   connection was closed: An unexpected
>   error occurred on a receive.
>
> Stack Trace:   at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>
> Exception Message: Unable to read data
>   from the transport connection: An
>   existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host.
>
> Stack Trace:   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   at
>   System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.StartReading(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   at
>   System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessRead(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)   at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest
>   request, Boolean userRetrievedStream,
>   Boolean probeRead)
>
> Exception Message: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the
>   remote host
>
> Stack Trace:   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)

Comment: Its difficult to read all story, please format your question.

Comment: Can you turn on tracing to see what's happening on the service side? Here's a screen cast that shows you how http://rocksolidknowledge.com/ScreenCasts.mvc/Watch?video=WCFTracing.wmv

Comment: Did you back then find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but for someone finding this : I had the same Exception . I figured out the error by defining a trace in web.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="C:/temp/tracelog.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" name="traceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
</system.diagnostics>
```

I ran the website locally, fired a few failing calls and the opened the tracelog selecting the failed entry, inside that entry I saw this exception :
The entity or complex type 'Person' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.
Constructing the person outside of the query fixed the issue so instead of :

```
var persons = (from p in db.Persons
                  select new Person
                  {
                      Id = p.Id,
                      Name = p.Name,
                      LastName = p.LastName,
                      Email = p.Email
                  }
              ).AsEnumerable();

  return persons;
```

I had to do :

```
var persons = (from p in db.Persons
                  select new 
                  {
                      Id = p.Id,
                      Name = p.Name,
                      LastName = p.LastName,
                      Email = p.Email
                  }
              ).AsEnumerable()
                //construct the complex type outside of DB  (to prevent the exception that model cannot be constructed in linq to entities)
                .Select(item =>

                    new Person
                    {
                        Id = item.Id,
                        Name = item.Name,
                        LastName = item.LastName,
                        Email = item.Email
                    }).ToList(); 

            return persons;
```